# Delete files from .app file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I got an ios app with some data, which store in .xml files. There are some changes in this file. I delete this file from project and add new file. But application still show me old data. And when i log path to file i see:

```
PermTour.app/greenline_en.xml
```

How to delete or replace this file?

Comment: Dit you try to clean you project (Product -> Clean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clean you project and deleting the App from the simulator. This way when You install a newer version it will copy all the new files..

Or try go to

> /Users/* *YourUser* */Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/* *iOS version* * /Applications/ **app folder* * /...

and delete the file.

Check Documentation: [link_01](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12) [link_02](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4)

Comment: Agreed. Clean all your targets/the project. Delete the app from the simulator and/or your device to make sure it uses latest version of file.